# Recursion method in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to use a recursive method to change strings to char arrays but i am getting an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
```

I want to solve this problem only using recursive method(not loop or toChar method)

```
public class Recur {
    public char[]  stringTochar(String str)
    {
        if (str != null && str.length() > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(str.charAt(0)) ;
            stringTochar(str.substring(1)); 
        }
        return stringTochar(str.substring(1)) ;
    }
}

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Recur recur= new Recur ();
        recur.stringTochar("this is a test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent `String#toCharArray`, and in particular, why reinvent it using *recursion*?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder learning purposes.

Comment: Your base case also calls the recursive function instead of stopping.

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633297/how-to-return-a-string-from-char-array-using-recursion-loop-java

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agreed, but usually recursion is hard to understand for beginners. Using simple data structures helps beginners to understand the concept per se. A tree can be way too complicated for a beginner to follow the recursion flow.

Comment: @m0skit0: Sorry, I actually meant to direct that comment at buni, not you. :-) (Why did you respond to my original question to the OP? That's what threw me off. You can only speculate why he/she is doing this; the OP can actually *answer*.)

Comment: @ buni: This problem is particularly poorly-suited to being solved with recursion. If you want to learn about recursion, I suggest a different task, such as (say) traversing a tree structure. The problem being that a recursive task must build up its results incrementally, which is difficult to do with a `char[]` return type.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, I thought it was about my comment. Looks like clear to me he/she is learning recursion, otherwise he/she better go back learning it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Recur
{
    private static char [] stringToChar (
        String str, char [] destination, int offset)
    {
        if (destination == null)
        {
            destination = new char [str.length ()];
            offset = 0;
        }

        if (offset < str.length ())
        {
            destination [offset] = str.charAt (offset);
            stringToChar (str, destination, offset + 1);
        }
        return destination;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        char [] chars = stringToChar ("this is a test", null, 0);

        for (char c: chars)
            System.out.println (c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
str.substring(1);
```

What happens when `str` is length 0?